# Create a dynamic dictionary from a column for keys and a column for values in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

If I have a table like below, how do I create a dictionary of `dynamic` type from the 2 columns? E.g. `{"a":"1", "b":"2", etc}`

```
let test = datatable (
    keys: string,
    vals: string
) [
    "a,b,c,d", "1,2,3,4" 
];
```

There is the `split()` and `zip()` function but they create array of arrays and that doesn't work with `todynamic()`

Comment: Shouldn't it be "a,b,c,d", **"1,2,3,4"**?

Comment: d'oh, yeah, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate variation

```
let test = datatable (keys: string, vals: string) ["a,b,c,d", "1,2,3,4"];
test
| mv-apply k = split(keys, ",") to typeof(string)
          ,v = split(vals, ",") to typeof(string) 
           on (summarize make_bag(bag_pack(k, v)))
```

| keys | vals | bag_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a,b,c,d | 1,2,3,4 | {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4"} |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/dumarkovadx.westeurope.dev/databases/mydb?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3WPTQvCMAyG74P9h5eeWogHP06Kv0RkZFsdo60raxxM/PF2IsOLCTm8kOcJ8VYgNgnOaFly195COzunI5KM/b0jTOzXZHBRTDU11CqC2tKO9nRQ11NZLJqyeCFMG47Rz3BZmqLv5ePL26QMZIDM0Q43/RWWBdaiaUWWo/8Q/DIY7tDpEQKP/dMisLNVzZ3OU0VunHb5A2PMG7M5GDzqAAAA)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, assuming both input arrays have the same length:

```
test
| extend keys = split(keys, ","), 
         vals = split(vals, ",") 
| mv-apply with_itemindex = i k = keys to typeof(string) on (
   summarize bag = make_bag(pack(k, vals[i])) 
)
| project bag
```